# Property 'dataTableExt' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>' - when trying to use jQuery DataTables with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, datatables

I have prepared a simple [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/asjuvqdz/) demo, which shows a jQuery DataTable with clickable rows and checkbox filtering:

[image: animated screenshot]

When I try to convert my code to TypeScript (here a not really working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-datatables) demo), then I have 2 errors displayed in VS Code:

> Property 'dataTableExt' does not exist on type 'JQuery' (for the $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push line)

> No overload matches this call (for the renderAvgData call)

I have searched around, on GitHub and at the DataTable forum, but hasn't been able to find a resolution for that.

Below is the copy of my working Javascript code (same as in the  jsFiddle):

```js
'use strict;'

function renderOpenElo(data, typeStr, row, meta) {
  return typeStr === 'display' ? '<SPAN CLASS="xlarge">&rtri;</SPAN> ' + data : data;
}

function renderAvgData(data) {
  return '<TABLE WIDTH=100%>' +
    '<TR><TH>Average score: ' + data.avg_score + '</TH></TR>' +
    '<TR><TH>Average time: ' + data.avg_time + '</TH></TR></TABLE>';
}

jQuery(function() {
  var topTable = $('#topTable').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://wordsbyfarber.com/ru/top-5',
    pageLength: 5,
    order: [
      [0, 'desc']
    ],
    columns: [{
        data: 'elo',
        searchable: false,
        className: 'details-control',
        render: renderOpenElo
      },
      {
        data: 'uid',
        className: 'dt-right'
      }
    ]
  });

  $('#topTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
    var span = $(this).find('span').first();
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = topTable.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      row.child.hide();
      span.html('&rtri;');
    } else {
      row.child(renderAvgData(row.data())).show();
      span.html('&dtri;');
    }
  });

  $('#below,#middle,#above').click(function() {
    topTable.draw();
  });

  $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex, row) {
      if ('topTable' == oSettings.nTable.id) {
        console.log(row);

        if (row.uid < 10000) {
          return $('#below').is(':checked');
        }

        if (10000 < row.uid && row.uid < 20000) {
          return $('#middle').is(':checked');
        }

        return $('#above').is(':checked');
      }

      return true;
    }
  );
});
```

```css
td.details-control {
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.xlarge {
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<p align="center">Show user ids:
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="below" checked> Below 10k </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="middle" checked> 10k - 20k </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="above" checked> Above 20k </label>
</p>

<table id="topTable" class="stripe" width=100%>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Elo</th>
      <th>User id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin author has been very nice to answer both my questions in the [DataTables forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/76627/how-to-use-fn-datatableext-with-typescript):

1. The [$.fn.dataTable.ext.search](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search) should be used for filtering
2. The `.show()` error message has been resolved in DataTables version 1.13.5